# JSP / Javascript / CSS : auto resize div based on window size

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

I created a "master page" in jsp using frameset, and I included the master page in my other jsps where i have a  in the  where the contents will be. How can I change the size of the  whenever the window size changes?

Below is my sample code :

masterPage.jsp

```
<html>
<frameset style="border: 0;" rows="135,*,38" style="z-index:1" >
    <frame id="headerFrame" noresize="noresize" name="ffwHeader" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="header.jsp" style="z-index:1" />
    <frame name="ffwMenu" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="menu.jsp" style="z-index:3" />
    <frame name="ffwFooter" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" src="footer.jsp" style="z-index:1" />
</frameset>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload A Disposition Rule</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, div, iframe { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
        iframe { display:block; width:100%; border:none; }
    </style>
</head>

<body >
    <div id="bodydiv" align="center" style="position:fixed; top:135px;left:182px; z-index:2; bottom: 38px;  height:  510px; width: 1080px; overflow: auto; ">
        <!--contents-->
    </div>
    <iframe src="masterPage.jsp" name="masterPage" />
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your `bodydiv` is defined as

```
    <div id="bodydiv" align="center" style="position:fixed; top:135px;left:182px; z-index:2; bottom: 38px;  height:  510px; width: 1080px; overflow: auto; ">
```

Since you specified in the comment to the first answer by @user8900 that you want the `bodydiv` to be resizable when the window size changes, it sounds like you want to alter the `width` style attribute on your `div`.

```
    <div id="bodydiv" align="center" style="position:fixed; top:135px;left:182px; z-index:2; bottom: 38px;  height:  510px; width: '100%'; overflow: auto; ">
```

At that point, however, I think you could probably just remove the `width` style attribute from the `div` altogether.  Further, as a general coding style note, you should think about moving all of your CSS `style` definitions to a `.css` file (or at least the existing `<style>` head section.)

```
<head>
    <title>Upload A Disposition Rule</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, div, iframe { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
        iframe { display:block; width:100%; border:none; }
        #bodydiv { position:fixed; top:135px;left:182px; z-index:2; bottom: 38px;  height:  510px; width: '100%'; overflow: auto; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bodydiv" align="center">
        <!--contents-->
    </div>
    (etc...)
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the size of the iframe relative to the 'window' size, try using percentage values - with the body width at 100% E.g.

```
<iframe src="masterPage.jsp" name="masterPage" style="width: 80%; height: 80%;" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what i what need is to change the <div id="bodydiv"> to be resizable relative to the window size